# explode and check if exist

Tags: php, mysql

this is MySQL table structure:

TABLE: **products**

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|   id    |             product_ids            |
|   1     |              51                    |
|   2     |              616,2,38              |
|   3     |              (NULL)                |
|   4     |              426,605,604           |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

What im looking is a way for the code to check if the id 605 exists in `product_ids` row, and if it does to replace for another ID:

any idea how can i accomplish this?

I was thinking of a sql QUERY...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm confused by a table that contains product `id`s *and* `product_ids`. Is it like a "related products" type of system?

Comment: yeah something like that, but im looking for a way to replace certain ID from the product_ids... any way i can do this directly from a SQL query??

Comment: you should really read about database normalization if you use database normalization your query should be easy and fast.. now you get bad php and sql answers... but check the MySQL function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set that should help you...

Comment: I suggest restructuring things so that each row only defines a relationship between two products. To associate one product with three other products, that product would have three rows -- one row for each related product. That way you can just perform a SQL `update` where `related_product_id=605`.

Comment: what do u think of this sql query? 

`$sql = "update products SET product_ids=TRIM(BOTH ',' from (select replace(CONCAT(',',product_ids,','), ',605,', ',777,'))) WHERE FIND_IN_SET('605',product_ids)>0";` 

seems to be doing just what i needed any thoughts about this query?

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products"; 
$r1=$con->execute_query($sql);

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {       
  if($row1['product_ids']) {
    $data = preg_split('/,/', $row1['product_ids']);
     if(is_array($data)) {
       foreach($data as $key => $value) {
           if($value == 605) {
               echo $value;
           }
       }
     }
  }   
}
```

Check it out on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/2BKJXHRa)

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   

    if($row1['product_ids']){
      $val_changed = false;
      $prod_ids = $row1['product_ids'];
      $ids = explode(',', $prod_ids);
      for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
        if($ids[$i] === '605') {
          $ids[$i] = $new_id;
          $val_changed = true;
        }
      }

      if($val_changed) {
        $prod_ids = implode(',', $ids);
        //update db with new value $prod_ids
      }
    }
}
```

To get only records that have the id you're looking for, and use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to change the value, and update the table with the new value

```
$new_id = '999';
$new_val = preg_replace('/,605,/', $new_id, $row1['product_ids']);
```

Comment: This won't match a `product_id` of '25,50,605'.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set for denormalization problem

Comment: This is a good idea, but link-only answers aren't as helpful as ones that provide some explanation. Possible to give an example or something?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland i found this code seems to be working just fine what do u think about it? update products SET product_ids=TRIM(BOTH ',' from (select replace(CONCAT(',',product_id,','), ',666,', ',605,'))) WHERE FIND_IN_SET('666',product_ids)>0

Comment: On request more or less. I think you should really use RPM code and copy the data into an new table structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd278/2  this structure  require an FULL TABLE SCAN atleast with this test data. the optimalizer could have chosen for a full scan because off the low number of records but product_ids should be in the column POSSIBLE_KEYS if The optimizer sees it as an index it can possible use.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if it contains '605':

```
SELECT id, product_ids FROM products 
where product_ids REGEXP '^.*[^\d]605(?!\d).*$'
```

Comment: this is, by the way, a very good example why we shouldn't use multiple values in the same field!

Now once you have it - you can do whatever you want, you can play with it:

```
$new_product_ids = preg_replace('/^(.*[^\d])(605)(?!\d)(.*)$/','${1}new_id${3}',$row1['product_ids']);
```

and update the row:

```
update products set product_ids = '$new_product_ids' where id = $id
```

Comment: What about a product_id of "1605" or "6050"?

Comment: Care to elaborate? Not being able to match particular id numbers seems like a pretty big problem...

Comment: My original comment still applies. My concerns: 1) `str_replace` incorrectly changes 1605, 6050, 12605234, etc. 2) regex is probably overkill in this context

Comment: @showdev damn... you're right... okay fixed. More complicated than I originally thought - it is an overkill indeed. Though it's nice to know how to do it - I have to admit that I'd probably split the string on comma if I have to do it at work

Comment: I agree, experimentation can be valuable. Your latest edit seems to work -- though I would do `'${1}'.$new_id.'${3}'` instead. Removed downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Query with Regex (Fancy!):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_ids REGEXP '^[^0-9]605[^0-9]$';
```

Script to modify data:

```
while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $r1, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
{   
    $product_ids = explode( ',', $row1['product_ids'] );

    if( ( $key = array_search( '605', $product_ids ) ) !== FALSE )
    {
        $product_ids[$key] = $new_id_number;

        $product_ids = implode( ',', $product_ids );

        // Enter Code to Update Table Here
    }
}
```